# Using Scrapy as a consumer with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy as a consumer with using RabbitMQ.

Here's my code snippet:

```
def runTester(body):
    spider = MySpider(domain=body["url"], body=body)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
    log.start()
    reactor.run()


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    body = json.loads(body)
    runTester(body)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=settings.RABBITMQ_HOST))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=settings.RABBITMQ_TESTER_QUEUE, durable=True)
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=settings.RABBITMQ_TESTER_QUEUE)
    channel.start_consuming()
```

As you can see the problem is the reactor shutdowns when the first message is consumed and spider is run. What is the workaround this?

I want to be able to keep the reactor running while keep running new crawlers all the time as messages are received from the RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use [scrapy daemon](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) api to launch spiders, upon getting a spider request you'll then use [curl](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm) like this:

```
reply = {}
args = ['curl',
        'http://localhost:6800/schedule.json',
        '-d', 'project=myproject', ] + flat_args
json_reply = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
try:
    reply = json.loads(json_reply)
    if reply['status'] != 'ok':
        logger.error('Error in spider: %r: %r.', args, reply)
    else:
        logger.debug('Started spider: %r: %r.', args, reply)
except Exception:
    logger.error('Error starting spider: %r: %r.', args, json_reply)
return reply
```

what will launch a sub process that will actually do:

```
$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider
```

scrapy daemon was built to manage spiders launching and has many other useful features like deploying new spider version in using a simple `scrapy deploy` command, monitor and balance multiple spiders etc.

Comment: This works but it is not running the scrapy process instantly but rather after some time. Can you please let me know how can we instantly run the spider after scheduling it?

Comment: The question asked about consuming from RabbitMQ, not about submitting jobs to scrapyd. I too, would like good examples of using scrapyd with RabbitMQ.

Comment: For every curl request scrapyd spawns a process, hoping that's not a good idea to spawn a process for every url request [please check](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html)